# Terminology: Is there a word/phrase that descibes the purpose of the keywords "class", "struct", "interface", "enum"?

Tags: keyword, terminology

Greetings StackOverflow,

While doing some reflection programming in C# I got to thinking about the keywords used to define classes, structures and interfaces. There are keywords like "public" and "internal" which are called "access modifiers". Then you've got the "sealed" keyword which is a sort of "inheritance modifier". In total you get a "type declaration", but what word or phrase describes the keywords "class", "interface", or "struct"?

I couldn't find anything after doing some Google searching, there wasn't anything concrete I could find in the C# language specification, and a much more experienced co-worker and I were talking about it and he didn't know either. Together we thought the phrase "type classification" might work; as the keywords describe what "kind" of type they are. However, it also sounds a bit too broad so I'm hoping for a better term/phrase.

Anyone know the proper term/phrase the effectively describes this group of keywords?

Comment: Probably "a kind of non-simple type", or "a kind of non-primitive type" or "a kind of definable type".